# Handle Whitespace and special character in shell script (using gio)

Tags: linux, bash, filepath, gio

Hy,

I am trying to handle white spaces and special characters like "&" in a shell script which is supposed to set custom directory icons using gio in Ubuntu 18.04.

When directory names consist only of a single word eg. MyFolder the following script works just fine:

```
for dir in $(find "$PWD" -type d); do
icon="/.FolderIcon.png"
iconLocation="$dir$icon"
if [ -a "$iconLocation" ]; then
front="file://"
gio set "$dir" metadata::custom-icon "$front$iconLocation"
fi
done
```

However when the directory is named eg. "A & B" the above script does not change the icon of the respective directory.

So my question is: Is there a way to handle directories named like "A & B" in my script?

Comment: `for dir in $(find ...)` is [BashPitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) #1 -- it's an antipattern in and of itself. See also [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Please review the tags you applied to your question. [edit] your question to delete those that don't really fit. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Thank you very much for your tips and comments! I will do my best to improve my bash understanding and stick to the conventions!

Answer (score 2):

First, `for var in $(cmd)` is generally an antipattern.

In most cases, what you'd probably want is something like suggested in https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 -

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do 
  # stuff ...
done < <(find "$PWD" -type d -print0)
```

But for this particular example, you might just use `shopt -s globstar`.
I made a directory with an `A & B` subdirectory and ran this test loop:

```
$: shopt -s globstar
$: for d in **/; do touch "$d.FolderIcon.png"; if [[ -e "$d.FolderIcon.png" ]]; then ls -l "$d.FolderIcon.png"; fi; done
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1234567 0 Apr 20 09:25 'A & B/.FolderIcon.png'
```

`**/` has some shortcomings - it won't find hidden directories, for example, or anything beneath them. It *is* pretty metacharacter-safe as long as you quote your variables, though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and very helpful reply!

Comment: I just wonder, if the touch command has a special purpose I am not yet aware of? In my case it had the unwanted effected of creating an empty "FolderIcon.png" file if none existed at the respective location so far. This lead to broken directory Icons since an empty file was used as custom icon.

Comment: I was just creating a file so it would exist for the test in this example, for my own convenience. I tested with a larger list of directories to see how it worked, and forgot to take that out for this shortened list. xD

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer of Paul Hodges the following solution finally worked for me:

```
shopt -s globstar
location="/path/to/location/you/want/to/modify"
prefix="file://"
for d in **/; do  
if [[ -e "$d.FolderIcon.png" ]]; 
then gio set "$d" metadata::custom-icon "$prefix$location/$d.FolderIcon.png"; 
fi; 
done
```